# Include sections to multiple appendices' table of contents using tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, appendices, tocloft, appendix

I am creating a table of contents (TOC) for multiple appendices in my document using the package `tocloft`, but in the printed TOC I can only see the names (head) of my appendices and not the sections within each of these appendices. How can I add `\section` to my TOC?

I am using the (example) code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{}
\newlistof{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}
\newcommand{\newappendix}[1]{\section*{#1}\appendices{#1}}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
\addtocounter{section}{1}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Conclusion}

\lipsum[1-2]

\clearpage

\appendix

\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{section}\arabic{figure}}

\begin{center}
{\large \textbf{Appendices}}
\end{center}


%%% APPENDICES' TABLE OF CONTENTS
\listofappendices

\clearpage 

\newappendix{Appendix I}

\section{Content 1}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Content 2}
\lipsum[1-1]

\clearpage

\newappendix{Appendix II}

\section{Content 1}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Content 2}
\lipsum[1-1]

\clearpage

\newappendix{Appendix III}

\section{Content 1}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Content 2}
\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

EDITED:

The TOC I have with my code:
[image: TOC I have]

The TOC I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sections are listed in the document's TOC (`\tableofcontents`). You have defined a new `\listofappendices` so you have to get your appendix sections listed in that. Try this:

```
% tocappendixprob.tex  SE 585983

\documentclass{article}   %%%%% ??????????????????
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{}
\newlistof{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}
\newcommand{\newappendix}[1]{\section*{#1}\appendices{#1}}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

% appendix sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\appsec}[1]{\section{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{apc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}\par}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Introduction}
\addtocounter{section}{1}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Conclusion}

\lipsum[1-2]

\clearpage

\appendix

\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{section}\arabic{figure}}

\begin{center}
{\large \textbf{Appendices}}
\end{center}


%%% APPENDICES' TABLE OF CONTENTS
\listofappendices

\clearpage 

\newappendix{Appendix I}

\appsec{Content 1}
\lipsum[1-1]

\appsec{Content 2}
\lipsum[1-1]

\clearpage

\newappendix{Appendix II}

\section{Content 1}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Content 2}
\lipsum[1-1]

\clearpage

\newappendix{Appendix III}

\section{Content 1}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Content 2}
\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

The above produces a warning about a destination with the same identifier, which was also produced with your MWE after I added the `\documentclass{article}` to get it to compile.

I don't necessarily recommend my `\appsec` solution as I don't know what you really want; in any case I suggest that you change the format of the Appendix titles in the listing.

Please read again the "New list of ..." section in the `tocloft` manual.
[image]

Comment: Peter, you code gets closer. Is it possible to format it as I use in my example? Include the sections below the "Appendix" with the same format but with indentation, and the dots to the page number. Then add some vertical space between the last section of each appendix and the next appendix.